# Laravel : Pusher listen for private channel with unique id

Tags: php, laravel, events, laravel-5, pusher

I have a news feed, If user `X` commented on user `Y`'s post then user `Y` should get a notification. **Now the issue is that user `Y` dont have to the post id on which user `X` commented on :**

```
// Create comment 
$comment = new Comment;
$comment->post_id = $post_id;
$comment->user_id = $user_id;
$comment->body = $body;
$comment->save();

// Save activity in database
$newUser = PostActivity::firstOrCreate([
    'post_id'   => $post_id,
],[
    'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
    'post_id' => $post_id,
    'seen'    => '0'
]);

// Dispatch event with newly created comment

FeedCommentActivity::dispatch($comment);
```

The event :

```
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new PrivateChannel('post-comment-activity.' .$this->activity->post_id);
}
```

The channel :

```
Broadcast::channel('post-comment-activity.{postId}', function ($user, $postId) {
    // Lets say true for the time
    return true;
});
```

**And the listener, This is where my question arises that how can `postId` will come up here :**

> From where the `postId` will come to listen and match the channel is
>   listening .

```
window.Echo.channel('post-comment-activity' + postId)
        .listen('FeedCommentActivity', e => {
    console.log('New comment by a user');
    console.log(e);
});
```

**I want to notify the participator or the owner of the post to be notified when a new comment comes up.**

> What will be the way around it ? Any alternate way ?

Answer (score 3):

You would need to fetch all `Post` IDs of current user. Then subscribe to each related private channel independently.

This is not really scalable in your case.

You'd probably better have one private channel per user:

```
// routes/channels.php
Broadcast::channel('users.{user}', function ($currentUser, User $user) {
    return $currentUser->id === $user->id;
});
```

Then broadcast:

```
// app/Events/CommentCreated.php
class CommentCreated implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $comment;

    public function __construct(Comment $comment)
    {
        $this->comment = $comment;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('users.' .$this->comment->post->user_id);
    }
    // ...

// app/Observers/CommentObserver.php
class CommentObserver
{
    public function created(Comment $comment)
    {
        broadcast(new CommentCreated($comment))->toOthers();
    }
    //...
```

Then listen:

```
window.Echo.channel('users.' + userId).listen('CommentCreated', e => {
    console.log(e.comment);
});
```